# IID assumption for time series data

Tags: statistics, independence, time-series

How common or reasonable is to assume time-series data are independent and identically distributed? To do some theoretical analysis, I need the assumption but I am not sure about its validity.

Comment: With respect to time or between different time series?

Comment: With respect to time.

Comment: Brownian motion is the most familiar time series example, which is characterized your desired iid. Check the definition of Brownian motion.